# /opt/splunk/bin/splunk: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

When I try start splunk without sudo (or even logged in as root), I get a "no such file or directory" error. The file's definitely there though, it's not even a symlink. It works with sudo, but then ps shows nothing's running and I can't access it through the web portal.

```
$ /opt/splunk/bin/splunk start
-bash: /opt/splunk/bin/splunk: No such file or directory
$ sudo /opt/splunk/bin/splunk start
$ ps aux | grep splunk
marco    25963  0.0  0.1   7972   900 pts/0    S+   22:58   0:00 grep splunk
```

Any ideas what's up? I've accepted the license (`sudo splunk start --accept-license`) and changed the port to 8001 (`sudo ./splunk set web-port 8001`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it! I had installed the 32 bit deb on a 64 bit server, which caused this.

Comment: If this solves your question, please mark it with a check mark when you can.

Answer (score 0):

That error is a classic symptom of a script for which the program named in the first line (the line starting with `#!` — the so-called "shebang" line) does not exist.  Type `head -5 /opt/splunk/bin/splunk` and see what shell is named in the shebang line (e.g., Python, Perl, Ruby, etc.).  That file either doesn't exist or is not executable by you.